# How do you stop a sound from playing again after a new view is loaded? (Xcode4.2)

Tags: xcode4.2

I have a sound file that plays when the main view loads and some buttons that have a modal link to other views. The sound file plays great when I open up the app, but then it plays everytime I navigate back to the main view. I stopped this by declaring an integer variable with a value and putting the audio file in an if statement, and then I changed the variable value when a button is pressed, but that was with xcode 3 without any of that cool storyboarding... Obviously that method wouldn't work with 4.2 because storyboard overrides the -(IBAction) code block, but I tried it (to no avail) anyways. 
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can set you flag inside the viewWillDisappear delegate.

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated

this should work